How do webhooks work in contrast to the typical client-server model
In the typical client-server model, a server cannot send data to a client without an explicit request from the client. However, webhooks seem to operate differently.
I understand that webhooks allow a server to push data to a client when certain events occur, without the client continuously polling for updates. But I'm unsure about the underlying mechanism.
My questions are:

How do webhooks overcome the limitation of the standard client-server model?
What's the initial setup process for implementing webhooks?
How is the security of webhook communications ensured?
Are there any potential drawbacks or limitations to using webhooks?

I'd appreciate a clear explanation of the webhook mechanism and how it differs from traditional client-server communication. Code examples or diagrams would be helpful if possible.


How do webhooks overcome the limitation of the standard client-server model?

They don't. A webhook is just web service with a buzzword attached that implies it is only intended to be called by one specific client in an automated fashion.

In the typical client-server model, a server cannot send data to a client without an explicit request from the client.

Web browsers are almost always implemented as HTTP clients.
They make requests to HTTP servers which send a response.
HTTP servers are just software though. There's nothing preventing a piece of software being both an HTTP client and an HTTP server.
For a really simple example, think of all the server side programming languages which let you use cURL, fetch, or another HTTP client API.

What's the initial setup process for implementing webhooks?

The same as any other web service.

How is the security of webhook communications ensured?

However you like. The buzzword doesn't imply any particular form of security. (HTTPS and some authentication is usually expected but that's not particular to webhooks).

Are there any potential drawbacks or limitations to using webhooks?

Just the usual ones that apply to any web service.
